# How to display a translated string on two rows

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have to make a simple react component which displays a translated string on two rows, second row must start always with the third word.

example:

```
<div className="parent">
  <p>{t('myText')}</p>
</div>
```

myText value from the translation file is = "Text that I want to display"

I tried using this "`Text that \n I want to display`" but didn't work.

which would be the best and the simplest way to solve this?

Comment: I think you cannot do it with JavaScript directly, without using innerHtml changes, which is not recommended. Assuming that `t(..)` is a function you wrote, replace it with **a custom component** that takes the text as a property, splits the text and returns a `<div>[text-part-1]<br>[text-part-2]</div>`. Or some HTML content of the kind.

Comment: Since you might be using JS, you can split the string into multiple words and add them inside multiple divs which will automatically be in a new line.

Comment: Try using CSS to preserve the line break: `<span style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>{t('myText')}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Use p tag it separated blocks by blank lines

```
<div className="parent">
  <p>Text1</p>
  <p>Text1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you need code in react.js. Here is a component code.

```
import React from 'react';

function TwoRowText(props) {
    const { text } = props;
    
    // Split the string on spaces
    const words = text.split(' ');

    // Make sure there are at least three words
    if (words.length < 3) {
        return <div className="parent">{text}</div>;
    }

    // Join the first two words and then the rest
    const firstRow = words.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
    const secondRow = words.slice(2).join(' ');

    return (
        <div className="parent">
            <div>{firstRow}</div>
            <div>{secondRow}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TwoRowText;
```

**Jsx file code**

```
<TwoRowText text={t('myText')} />
```